# Hide free shipping when specific coupons are applied in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I'm trying to set it so that for a specific coupon then free shipping is not available.

I then tried this, but it doesn't work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_packages', function( $packages ) {
    $applied_coupons = WC()->session->get( 'applied_coupons', array() );
    if ( ! empty( $applied_coupons ) ) {
        
        if (in_array("544", $applied_coupons))
        {
        
            $free_shipping_id_11 = 'free_shipping:11';
            if($free_shipping_id_11){
                unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $free_shipping_id_11 ]);
            }
            $free_shipping_id_9 = 'free_shipping:9';
            if($free_shipping_id_9){
                unset($packages[0]['rates'][ $free_shipping_id_9 ]);
            }
        
        }
        
    }
    return $packages;
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    $targeted_coupons = array("544"); // Here set your related coupon codes

    $applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();

    if ( ! empty($applied_coupons) && array_intersect( $targeted_coupons, $applied_coupons ) ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:**
>
> 1. This code is already saved on your functions.php file.
> 2. In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save. 
>    **You are done** and you can test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work?
https://www.rolypoly.co.za/